# Dandruff, or something else?

Tags: hair

I am a white male with short hair--about an inch to four inches, depending on how long I've gone without a haircut. I've had problems with dandruff for a long time, or so I thought. With different dandruff shampoos not really helping, I'm beginning to think that this isn't dandruff. Dandruff is a problem with the scalp. If I scratch my head in one spot without disturbing the hair strands much, nothing falls out. But if I don't touch my scalp at all and brush my hair back and forth with my fingers, it starts raining cats, dogs, and very small white particles that look like dried skin. But these particles don't look like the yellowed, slightly larger pieces of skin and oil that I've heard come with dandruff. So now I really don't know what to do. I haven't been to a dermatologist about this yet, granted, but:

- I have tried several different shampoos and conditioners for dandruff without much luck
- I have generally good skin on my face (almost always clear, although slightly oily) and body (some areas that are sensitive to dryness after hot showers)
- I wash regularly, and wash my hair every two or three days (although I have tried washing my hair every day, resulting in just an itchy scalp with more of the same problem)
- I live in College Station, Texas, if that helps with any climate or humidity questions
- I use a shampoo and conditioner meant for moisturizing the hair and scalp, and a leave-in tea tree conditioner that helps keeps my hair feel nice and smooth and not dry.

Any advice?

Comment: Hi there! This question is actually asking for personal diagnosis, but if you could just reword the question to something more general, we might be able to help. Also, searching this site might help too!